# Скрипт, обрезающий строки

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти скрипт, обрезающий строки.

В интернет-магазине описания товаров слишком длинные. Хотелось бы сократить их до определённого количества строк(например до 3). Но проблема в том, что описания созданы через визивиг и поэтому в тексте содержатся различные тэги типа span, div, p и т.д.

Однако каждое описание находится в контейнере .text.

Хотелось бы что-нибудь типа такого

```
jQuery('.text').correctLines( 3, '' );
```

Вот пример кода

```
<article class="item2">
<div class="top">
    <h1>
        <a data-product="1" href="products/apple-iphone-4s-16gb">Apple iPhone 4S 16Gb</a>
    </h1>

    <form class="variants" action="/cart">
        <span class="price">44 000&nbsp;<span class="currency">руб</span></span>

        <input id="variants_1" name="variant" value="1" type="radio" class="variant_radiobutton" checked style="display:none;"/>

        <input type="submit" class="button buy" value="Купить" data-result-text="Добавлено" />

        <a class="credit" href="#">В кредит</a>

        <span class="price">42 000&nbsp;<span class="currency">руб</span></span>

        <input id="variants_2" name="variant" value="2" type="radio" class="variant_radiobutton"  style="display:none;"/>

        <input type="submit" class="button buy" value="Купить" data-result-text="Добавлено" />

        <a class="credit" href="#">В кредит</a>

    </form>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
    <div class="text"><p><span>iPhone 4 получил 3,5-дюймовый дисплей с разрешением 960 x 640 пикселей. Толщина устройства всего 9,3 мм. Передняя и задняя стороны аппарата обе плоские, выполнены из стекла, торцевая окантовка - стальная. У телефона есть фронтальная камера для видеозвонков, дополнительный микрофон для шумоподавления, а слот SIM сменился на Micro SIM. Батарея обеспечивает до 14 часов в режиме разговора, 6/10 часов в режиме веб-серфинга по 3G/Wi-Fi, 10 часов просмотра видео, 40 часов прослушивания музыки и 300 часов режима ожидания. Кроме того, добавлена поддержка Wi-Fi 802.11n. Разрешение основной камеры 5 МП, имеется поддержка видеосъемки с разрешением 1280 x 720 пикселей со скоростью 30 кадров в секунду.Дисплей 3,5 дюйма, 640х960 точек, IPS, олеофобное покрытие / Двухъядерный A5 Чип, Графический ускоритель PowerVR SGX543MP2 / 8-мегапиксельная фотокамера, HD видео (1080pх) / Bluetooth 4.0 и Wi-Fi 802.11b/g/n / гарантия - 12 месяцев.</span></p></div>
</div>
```

</article>

Вот попытка решения http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/crop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=jTruncate, увы, не знаю как оно себя с тегами поведет, все-таки обычно такие плагины предназначены для усечения чистого текста.